# Empty object while loading resource with ResourceManager (C++/CLI)

Tags: casting, c++-cli, resourcemanager

I'm trying to load one graphic resource (PNG image) which seems to be added to my project (I used 'Add item...' with the file placed at the main path).

The function I made is the next:

```
Image^ Camera::LoadResource( String^ file, String^ Res){
        String^ ressrc = file;      
        System::Reflection::Assembly^ execAssem = System::Reflection::Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();
        Resources::ResourceManager^ myres = gcnew Resources::ResourceManager(ressrc, execAssem);
        Object^ obj = myres->GetObject(Res);
        return dynamic_cast<Image^>(obj);

    }
```

But when I check 'obj', it has a null value. This function used to work on another project... what I'm doing wrong this time?

Thank you!

Comment: You are using the wrong Res string of course.  If you have no idea what it should be then look at the assembly manifest with ildasm.exe

Comment: This is my resource file opened with Visual Studio. It's included at the project, as you can see. And the string I use is "LED_green"

https://ibb.co/jVqU6a